# Wordpress img size too small because of the theme

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, image, size

My theme generate my img portfolio with this code :

```
<img width="222" height="440" src="#" class="attachment-portfolio" alt="#">
```

I found this code :

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php foreach($attachments as $attachment) {
        $alt = get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);                    
        $image_big =  wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'portfolio' ); ?>
        <div class="item">
            <?php echo $image_big ?>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

I'm not good in PHP but i understand that the image size is generate from "$image_big" ?

I found also this in my `function.php`

```
add_image_size('big',9999,400);
```

I try to change the width and height in the `add_image_size` but nothing happend on the website ! It's still `width="222" height="440"`
I would like the image to be 100% or around 800px width (if it's impossible to get % unit). What to do ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please explain what you expect. Currently its not clear what you want to archive. When you ask "`How can i remove the width and height ?`" I could answer _use your favourite editor and delete `width="222" height="440"`_ but this is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thank you @try-catch-finally :) 
I edit my post, i hope it's more clear now !

Comment: When you say 100% what do you expect? 100% of it's original width or 100% of the viewport? [Related documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) and cite: "`Although height and width are not required parameters, [...]. As mentioned before, use a value of 9999 to define the other dimension as the one to be considered when image resize is executed. `"

Comment: When i say 100% i want the img to be 100% width of the previous div who contain the <img>

Or (maybe more simple) i just want to change the width value ! When i try to change the add_image_size ('big',9999,400); with other value, nothing happend

Comment: Your code means "resize the image to at most 440px height and let the algorithm decide the width by preserving the aspect ratio". Now, since you'd like to create images up to 800px width, you may want to register an image size category with width and height `(category-name, 800, 9999)` and then use that category name. Now you get images up to 800px width and you could then use CSS to possibly limit the width by using `width: 100%`

Comment: I try it, the img is still generate with : `width="222" height ="440"`

I also get it in my code that it's not `big` that determinate the size but `portfolio`
`wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'portfolio'  ); ?>`
and i got : `add_image_size('portfolio',9999,440);` i also try to change the value ... but nothing change ! :(

Comment: Okay so i change this :
`wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'portfolio' ); ?>`
into this 
`wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' ); ?>`
full who is a default value img size for wordpress, and it change the size of my picture ! i still don't know why the `add_image_size` in my `function.php`didn't affect anything, but i resolve my problem !

Comment: Congratulations to solving your problem. Maybe you've called `add_image_size()` too late so the category name is not registered at the right moment? Since your problem is solved now, you change your question and ask why the `add_image_size()` doesn't work as expected. THis might be helpful to others.